# SFTP Connection Timeout

Tags: python, tcp, sftp, openssh

Using the pysftp package (wrapper for paramiko SSH client), I am encountering a timeout while establishing the connection.  This works about 80% of the time, but fails the other 20% (runs daily and fails 1-2 per week).  pysftp version is 0.2.9 running on RHEL 7.7.  The connection is within the corporate network (no firewalls or proxies).

```
            connection_options = pysftp.CnOpts()
            if args.debug:
                connection_options.log = True
            sftp = pysftp.Connection(host = 'server_name', username='xxxxx',
                                     private_key = file_name,
                                     private_key_pass = 'passphrase',
                                     cnopts=connection_options)
```

Debug log (last 2 lines shows the timeout):

```
2021-06-25 20:00:07,918:DEBUG:transport.py:33388:_log:1819:starting thread (client mode): 0xfcc96550
2021-06-25 20:00:07,919:DEBUG:transport.py:33388:_log:1819:Local version/idstring: SSH-2.0-paramiko_2.7.2
2021-06-25 20:00:07,992:DEBUG:transport.py:33388:_log:1819:Remote version/idstring: SSH-2.0-WRQReflectionforSecureIT_8.1 Build 94
2021-06-25 20:00:07,992:INFO:transport.py:33388:_log:1819:Connected (version 2.0, client WRQReflectionforSecureIT_8.1)
2021-06-25 20:00:08,000:DEBUG:transport.py:33388:_log:1819:kex algos:['diffie-hellman-group1-sha1', 'diffie-hellman-group14-sha1', 'diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1', 'diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256', 'gss-group1-sha1-toWM5Slw5Ew8Mqkay+al2g==', 'gss-gex-sha1-toWM5Slw5Ew8Mqkay+al2g=='] server key:['ssh-rsa-sha2-256@attachmate.com', 'ssh-rsa'] client encrypt:['aes128-ctr', 'aes192-ctr', 'aes256-ctr', 'aes128-cbc', 'aes192-cbc', 'aes256-cbc', '3des-cbc', 'blowfish-cbc', 'cast128-cbc', 'arcfour256', 'arcfour128', 'arcfour'] server encrypt:['aes128-ctr', 'aes192-ctr', 'aes256-ctr', 'aes128-cbc', 'aes192-cbc', 'aes256-cbc', '3des-cbc', 'blowfish-cbc', 'cast128-cbc', 'arcfour256', 'arcfour128', 'arcfour'] client mac:['hmac-sha256', 'hmac-sha2-256', 'hmac-sha1', 'hmac-md5', 'hmac-sha1-96', 'hmac-md5-96', 'hmac-ripemd160', 'hmac-sha512', 'hmac-sha2-512'] server mac:['hmac-sha256', 'hmac-sha2-256', 'hmac-sha1', 'hmac-md5', 'hmac-sha1-96', 'hmac-md5-96', 'hmac-ripemd160', 'hmac-sha512', 'hmac-sha2-512'] client compress:['zlib', 'none'] server compress:['zlib', 'none'] client lang:[''] server lang:[''] kex follows?False
2021-06-25 20:00:08,000:DEBUG:transport.py:33388:_log:1819:Kex agreed: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256
2021-06-25 20:00:08,000:DEBUG:transport.py:33388:_log:1819:HostKey agreed: ssh-rsa
2021-06-25 20:00:08,001:DEBUG:transport.py:33388:_log:1819:Cipher agreed: aes128-ctr
2021-06-25 20:00:08,001:DEBUG:transport.py:33388:_log:1819:MAC agreed: hmac-sha2-256
2021-06-25 20:00:08,001:DEBUG:transport.py:33388:_log:1819:Compression agreed: none
2021-06-25 20:00:08,365:DEBUG:transport.py:33388:_log:1819:Got server p (2048 bits)
2021-06-25 20:00:08,538:DEBUG:transport.py:33388:_log:1819:kex engine KexGexSHA256 specified hash_algo <built-in function openssl_sha256>
2021-06-25 20:00:08,539:DEBUG:transport.py:33388:_log:1819:Switch to new keys ...
2021-06-25 20:00:08,539:DEBUG:transport.py:33388:_log:1819:Host key verified (ssh-rsa)
2021-06-25 20:00:08,540:DEBUG:transport.py:33388:_log:1819:Attempting public-key auth...
2021-06-25 20:00:08,908:DEBUG:transport.py:33388:_log:1819:userauth is OK
2021-06-25 20:00:38,585:ERROR:mylogins_extract.py:33388:mylogins_extract:180:Authentication timeout.
```

Comment: I am not seeing those exceptions in the source code... Still digging... I'll be adding (edit) a path to the source of pysftp. EDIT: Edit queue is full, can you manually add the following path please? https://bitbucket.org/dundeemt/pysftp/src/master/

Comment: It is using http://www.paramiko.org/ for SSHv2, that's where the error messages are coming from.